# Why Does the as.numeric() Function Produce Different Results in R?

Tags: r

I am writing a short program in R that tells the user whether their input is numeric or not.
Here is my code:

```
numeric_check <- function() {
     input <- readline(prompt="Enter something: ")
     cat("Input: ", input, "\n")  
     cat("Input type: ", class(input), "\n")  
     check <- as.numeric(input)  
     cat("NA or number? ", check, "\n")  
     cat("Type:", class(check), "\n")
     if (is.na(check)) {
         print("Not numeric.")
     } else {
         print("Numeric.")
     }
 }
```

It works fine when I input a number.
However, when I input the string, "123", the "NA or number?" checkpoint prints out "NA", while the "Type" checkpoint prints out "numeric".
I checked the portion where I suspect might be the issue:

```
test <- as.numeric("123")
test
```

That shows up as

```
123
```

instead of "NA" as it does in my program above.
Why does the program print out "NA" for as.numeric("123") and when I check it individually, it prints out the numeric type 123?
If someone can point to what I have missed, I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: readline reads text: *A character vector of length one.* So when you give it `"123"` it sees `"\"123\""`.

Comment: I see. Okay, so RStudio sees it as `"\"123\""` and results in `"NA"` when `as.numeric()` is used. However, why does the `"Type"` checkpoint see `"NA"` as numeric?

Comment: NA doesn't have a single class attached to it. See `class(NA_real_)` or `class(NA_character_)`. Hence `class(as.numeric("\"123\""))` gives `numeric`.

Comment: Someone please post an answer! (The original poster is welcome/encouraged to do so.)

Comment: Why not just use  `is.numeric()` ?

Comment: Thank you, Andre Wildberg. For some reason my comment saying that I understand what happened disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question has been answered in the comments.

1. `readline` reads in "123" as ""123""
2. NA doesn't have a single class attached to it. Which is why my `Type` checkpoint didn't help with catching the original problem.
   Thanks to Andrew Wildberg for answering!